# Vue.js ajax request one step behind

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am using Laravel and Vue.

It seems like an ajax call is one step behind meaning that when I post a comment it doesn't show up,and then when I make another comment the previous one shows up on the screen.

To clarify, when I post a comment it is saved immediately in the database.

For the delete function,I need to click the delete button twice to get rid of the comment out of the screen.But, the data is removed from the database when I click the delete button once,but doesn't disappear until I click once again.

I don't know whats happening.I have been working on this the whole day.PLease help me out

Thanks for your help guys!!

Here is the Vue instance

```
new Vue({




el: '#comment',

data: {

    newComment: {
        id:'',
        reply: '',
        user_id:'',
        topic_id:''
    },

    edit: false,

    comments: []

},  

created: function () {
    this.$set('id', id)
    this.$set('topic_id')
},

methods: {

    fetchComment: function (topic_id) {
        this.$http.get('/api/fetch-comments/' + topic_id).then(function (data) {
            this.$set('comments',data['data'])
        })
    },

    showComment: function (id) {
        this.edit = true;
        this.$http.get('/api/comments/' + id, function(data) {
            this.newComment.id = data.id
            this.newComment.reply = data.reply
            this.newComment.topic_id = data.topic_id
            this.newComment.user_id = data.user_id
        })
    },

    editComment: function (id) {
        var comment = this.newComment

        this.newComment = { id:'', reply:'', topic_id:'',user_id:''}

        this.$http.patch('/api/comments/' + id, comment, function (data) {
            console.log(data)
        })

        this.fetchComment(topic_id)

        this.edit = false
    },

    deleteComment: function(id) {
        var ConfirmBox = confirm("削除しますか？")

        if(ConfirmBox) this.$http.delete('/api/comments/' + id)

        this.fetchComment(topic_id)
    },

    addNewComment: function () {
        var comment = this.newComment

        this.newComment = { reply:'',user_id:'',
        topic_id:'' }
        this.$http.post('/api/comments/', comment)
        this.fetchComment(topic_id)


    }


},

computed: {
    validation: function() {
            return {
                reply: !this.newComment.reply.trim()
            }
    }
}, 





ready: function () {
    this.fetchComment(topic_id)
}
});
```

Blade file

```
<script>
  var topic_id = '{{ $topic->id }}';
   var id = '{{ Auth::id() }}';
</script>


<div id="comment">



      <span v-for="comment in comments">

                <p> @{{ comment.reply }}</p>




            <div v-if="id == comment.user_id">
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" @click="showComment(comment.id)" >edit</button>
                     <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" @click="deleteComment(comment.id)">delete</button>
             </div>
        </span> 





<!-- Form -->
     @if(Auth::user())
        <hr style="margin-top:40px;">

        <div class="alert alert-success" v-show="!validation.reply">

            <p>what do u have to say?</p>

        </div>
        <form action="#" @submit.prevent="addNewComment">

            <div class="form-group">

                    <label for="reply"><h3>comment：</h3></label>
                    <textarea v-model="newComment.reply" name="reply" id="reply" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>

            </div>

            <input v-model="newComment.topic_id" type="hidden" name="topic_id" id="topic_id" value="{{$topic->id}}">
            <input v-model="newComment.user_id"  type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="{{Auth::id()}}">


            <div class="form-group">
                <button :disabled="!validation.reply" class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" v-if="!edit">post</button>

                <button :disabled="!validation.reply" class="btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit" v-if="edit" @click="editComment(newComment.id)">edit</button>
            </div>


        </form>
    @endif
```

Route

```
Route::get('/api/fetch-comments/{topic_id}', function($topic_id){
    return App\Comment::where(compact('topic_id'))->with('likes')->get();
});

Route::post('/api/comments/', function(){
    return App\Comment::create(Request::all());
});

Route::get('/api/comments/{id}', function($id) {
    return App\Comment::findOrFail($id);
});

Route::patch('/api/comments/{id}', function($id) {
    App\Comment::findOrFail($id)->update(Request::all());

});

Route::delete('/api/comments/{id}', function($id) {
   return App\Comment::destroy($id);

});
```

Comment: did you check the ajax response on clicking first delete? Is ajax actually calling by `vue` also you can check using `postman`? You first isolate your problem whether the problem is `vue` or `laravel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling two async functions without callbacks or promises in your `addNewComment` in your Vue code. This piece of code

```
addNewComment: function () {
    var comment = this.newComment

    this.newComment = { reply:'',user_id:'',
    topic_id:'' }
    this.$http.post('/api/comments/', comment)
    this.fetchComment(topic_id)
```

Should be like this

```
addNewComment: function () {
    var comment = this.newComment

    this.newComment = { reply:'',user_id:'',
    topic_id:'' }
    this.$http.post('/api/comments/', comment).then(function (response) {
        // should your topic_id var be defined here? 
        // that's also a problem if it is undefined
        this.fetchComment(topic_id)
    })
```

Other thing, I don't know why you are using the `$set` method in the `$get` call on `fetchComment` methods, it is not necesary, because your comments are already defined in the data atribute of your Vue instance, so just use `this.comments = data['data']`

Comment: Definitely, it isn't easy to start with a framework without a solid base on the language